# Can I emulate/virtualize Windows x86 in Apple ARM CPUs?

Tags: windows, parallels, arm, x86

I have a Windows software that only runs in Windows x86 and my current computer has an Apple ARM M1 CPU.

I can virtualize Windows 11 using ARM image in Parallels however, the software crashes.

Is there a way to virtualize or emulate Windows 10/11 x86 in my MAC?

Comment: “Is there a way to virtualize or emulate Windows 10/11 x86 in my MAC?” - No

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer: Yes!

I discovered a tool call UTM which enables virtualisation of ARM operating systems and emulation of other architectures (including x86)

https://github.com/utmapp/UTM

[image]

[image]

[image]

DISCLAIMER: I am not the creator and I am not related to this app

Answer (score 1):

Apple is actively refusing any support for x86 and x64 emulation on their ARM based systems.

Parallels was able to add support for x86 windows but was shortly denied after by an update from Apple.

Long answer short, if you need x86 support, get a windows computer or x86 compatible mac.

The best way to work with this on your mac, is by using a second windows computer and take control using Remote Desktop, by installing Microsoft RD Client on your mac.

Comment: Yes; Unfortunately the best way to get x86 Windows application emulation support on ARM Apple hardware is to use Windows on ARM but sadly that cannot be purchased individually. (Windows on ARM is capable of 32-bit and 64-bit x86 emulation on compatible  ARM64 hardware)

Comment: @LPChip It seems kind of strange that I cannot emulate x86 Windows but I can execute x86 Mac app with Rosetta

Comment: @Angel that's typical Apple for you. They block third party apps from doing it, but allow their own emulation just fine. Its not an incompatibility problem, its Apple actively blocking stuff. In case you was unaware, Rosetta was developed by Apple, and Parallels is a competitor.

Comment: @LPChip Hi, recently I discovered a tool call UTM which enables virtualisation of ARM operating systems and emulation of other architectures (including x86)